# Composition of invertible functions proof

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have this proof to do, I do not think it is too hard if you I know the rules I should apply. In particular, is there anything i can do with the -1's in this case?
If now, what rules can I apply to this to get this out?

> $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$

So I'm stuck here,

$$(f \circ g)^{-1} = (f(g(x)))^{-1}$$

For example, I'm relearning a lot of stuff, I remember learning something like this:

$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$

I'm thinking I can apply this? or is this result actually a result of the lemma I'm supposed to be proving anyway?

Help would be appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: The definition of $h^{-1}$ is that the composition $h^{-1}(h(x)) = x$ and $h(h^{-1}(x)) = x$. Can you apply this definition to $h = f \circ g$ to get the result?

Comment: It is sometimes referred to as the "Socks and Shoes" principle.  You first put on your socks and then you put on your shoes.  If you want to reverse this process, you must first take off your shoes before taking off your socks.

Comment: Nope, I still don't see it @Nick. If two functions are invertible, does that mean the author means they are inverse of each other? or just that they have inverses? I'm wondering if this is what the author means of it has something to do with the solution.

Comment: Lemma: if f and g are invertible functions and $f \circ g$ exists, then $f \circ g$ is invertible and $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ that is what I have to prove. @Nick

Comment: and to you too @JMoravitz

Comment: You type it correctly in the second comment but your first comment suggests that you don't know what that means.  Assuming $f$ and $g$ are invertible functions and the composition $f\circ g$ exists then not only is the composition invertible too but it's inverse is the composition of the inverses of the two functions in the other order, $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.  The hint again is to look closely at the definitions of what it means to be an invertible function and test to see if $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$ satisfies the properties of being the functional inverse of $f\circ g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following definition of inverse function:

> Let $F$ be a function. We say that $G$ is the inverse function of $F$ if it satisfies
>   $$
> G(F(x))=x,\ \forall x\in Dom\ F,
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> F(G(x))=x,\ \forall x\in Dom\ G.
> $$
>   In this case, we denote $G$ by $F^{-1}$.

We shall use the following basic stuff without mentioning:
i) $F^{-1}$ is unique;
ii) $(F^{-1})^{-1} = F$;
iii) $Im\ F^{-1} = Dom\ F$;
iv) $Im\ F = Dom\ F^{-1}$.

Let us consider the functions $f$ and $g$ of our problem.

Notice that there is a condition that is implicitly assumed. To be able to do the composition $f\circ g$, we must have that 
$Im\ g \subset Dom\ f$. On the other hand, to be able to do the composition $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$, we must have $Im\ f^{-1} \subset Dom\ g^{-1}$, then
$$
Dom\ f = Im\ f^{-1} \subset Dom\ g^{-1} = Im g.
$$
Therefore, the identity is implicitly assumed:

> $Im\ g= Dom\ f$.

Now, let us prove that $(f\circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.

The function $f^{-1}$ satisfies
$$
f^{-1}(f(x))=x,\ \forall x\in Dom\ f.
$$
In particular, for any $y\in Dom\ g$, we have that $g(y)\in Im g = Dom\ f$, and consequently, substituing $x$ by $g(y)$ above, we get
$$
f^{-1}(f(g(y)))=g(y),
$$
so $f^{-1}(f(g(y)))\in Im\ g = Dom\ g^{-1}$, and, applying $g^{-1}$ above, we get
$$
g^{-1}(f^{-1}(f(g(y))))=g^{-1}(g(y)) = y.
$$
This way we proved that

> $(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})((f\circ g)(y))=y,\ \forall y\in Dom\ g = Dom\ (f\circ g).$

Now, this fact is valid for any two invertible functions $f$, $g$ such that $Dom\ f= Im\ g$. But notice that
$$
Dom\ g^{-1}= Im\ g = Dom\ f = Im\ f^{-1}.
$$

Then the equality above is also valid if we replace $f$ by $g^{-1}$ and $g$ by $f^{-1}$. Then

> $(f\circ g)((g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})(y))=y,\ \forall y\in Dom\ (g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}).$

By the definition of inverse function, the two underlined properties imply that $(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})=(f\circ g)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for that @AndrePorto assumptions in your answer here were not made obvious in the book. At least it is not obvious to me.